# A non-degenerate martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, pr.probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, on which
$\mathcal{F}_t$ is filtration satisfying general conditions.
$W_t$ is
a standard Brownian motion.
Let $Y_t$ be a martingale given by
$$Y_t = \int_0^t \sigma_r d W_r$$
where $\sigma_t$ is a bounded $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable process.

The question is,
assume $\sigma_t>0$ almost surely for all $t$, then can we
prove
$$P(Y_1 = c) = 0$$
for all constant $c$?

Comment: I think the answer is no. You should be able to construct a counterexample by a continuous time change, or by an SDE of the form $dY=\min(f(t)Y,1)dt$ for suitable $f(t)$.

Comment: Dear George, By time-change, $Y_t$ is BM under new time scale.
In the SDE above, do you mean $d W_t$ instead of $d t$?
Even with this, I can not see the counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an explicit construction that gives a counterexample. 
For simplicity let $c=0$ (not important).

First, let $\alpha>0$ and consider the probability that a standard Brownian
motion started at 0 hits 0 at some time in the interval
$(\alpha t, \alpha t+t)$.
Then (1) this probability does not depend on $t$ (by Brownian scaling) --
call it $p_\alpha$; and (2) $p_\alpha\to 1$ as $\alpha\to 0$
(because with probability 1, the standard Brownian motion hits
0 at some time in the interval $(0,t)$).

Now we'll use this and Borel-Cantelli to show that with positive probability,
we can construct $\sigma$ and a sequence of times $t_n\uparrow 1$
such that $Y_{t_n}=1$ for all $n$.

Let $\alpha_n$ be some sequence decreasing to 0 quickly enough that
$\sum (1-p_{\alpha_n}) <\infty$.

Let $t_0=0$ and recursively define $t_1, t_2, \dots$ as follows.

Given $t_n<1$ and $Y(t_n)=0$, let $\sigma_t=\sqrt{\alpha_n}$
for $t\in(t_n, (1+t_n)/2)$, and let $\sigma_t=1$
for $t\in((1+t_n)/2, t_{n+1})$, where $t_{n+1}$ is defined by

$t_{n+1}=\inf \big[ t>(1+t_n)/2: Y_t=0 \big]$.

The idea of this definition: given $t_n<1$,
we divide the remaining time interval $(t_n, 1)$ into two
halves, and run BM at speed $\alpha_n$ on the first half
and at speed 1 on the second half, stopping as soon as we hit
0 during the second half.
Since we start at 0,
the probability that we DO hit 0 at some point during the second
half is easily seen to be $p_{\alpha_n}$ as defined above.
Hence
$P(t_{n+1}<1 | t_n<1)=p_{\alpha_n}$.

Now using Borel-Cantelli (and reasoning straightforwardly about independence)
we get that there is positive probability that
$t_n<1$ for all $n$. In that case also $t_n\uparrow 1$
(since $1-t_{n+1}<(1-t_{n})/2$).
Also $Y_{t_n}=0$ for all $n$ by construction.
But the process $Y_t$ is continuous
(since $\sigma_t$ is bounded). So then also $Y_1=0$ as desired.

Comment: Dear James, Elegant example. In the above,$\sigma_t$ in the
first half shall be $\sigma_t = \sqrt{\alpha_n}$? Also, if we 
restrict $\alpha_t >K>0$ for some constant $K$, then is it possible to prove the above claim $P(Y_1 = c) = 0$?

Comment: Hi Kenneth - yes indeed I meant $\sqrt{\alpha_n}$, thanks, edited. 

Comment: I think if $\sigma$ is bounded away from zero as well as from above, then indeed your conclusion follows. Haven't though through the details, but I think you can get a uniform bound above on $P(Y_1=0 | \cal{F}_t)$ for all $t<1$, since it's bounded above by the probability of seeing a zero of a BM in a time interval $x(1-t), y(1-t)$ for some fixed $x$, $y$, which can be bounded above uniformly in the starting point in a way that doesn't depend on $t$. But the event $Y_1=0$ is also determined by the intersection of $\cal{F}_t$ over $t<1$; I think this can be used to give the desired conclusion. 

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I could not follow your idea completely. Could you make it a bit more detail?

Comment: @James: If $\sigma$ is also bounded away from zero, then I *think* that $Y_1$ has an absolutely continuous probability distribution, with bounded density.

Comment: @George, I appreciate if you can post a short hint in the case of $\sigma$ is bounded away from zero. Thanks.

Comment: George's comment may relate to a much better idea than mine... but for what it's worth, here's what I had in mind. Consider the event $Y_1=0$. Since $Y$ is continuous, this event is measurable with respect to $\cal{F}_{1-}=\sigma(\cal{F}_t, t<1)$. So with probability 1, $I(Y_1=0)=\lim_{t\to1} P(Y_1=0|\cal{F}_t)$ (eg see "Levy's zero-one law" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems ). 

So to show $P(Y_1=0)=0$ it will be enough to show that $P(Y_1=0|\cal{F}_t)<a$ a.s.\ for all $t$, for some constant $a<1$.

continues....

Comment: So consider $P(Y_1=0|\cal{F}_t)$, where $Y_t=u$. Since the "speed"
with which we run the BM is bounded above and away from 0, this conditional probability is bounded above by the probability that a standard BM, started from $u$, hits 0 somewhere in the interval $(x(1-t), y(1-t)$, where $x$ and $y$ are constants (depending on the upper and lower bounds on $\sigma$). But that probability is bounded above, uniformly in $t$ and $u$. 

Comment: @kenneth: It was just a thought, so I'm not sure if it works out. I was originally thinking of using a time change. Alternatively, if you can find $p(x,t)\ge0$ which tends weakly to the Dirac delta function at $t=0$ and satisfies $\max(cp_{xx},Cp_{xx})\le p_t$ then $p(t,x)$ bounds the density of any such $Y_t$ subject to $c\le\frac12\sigma^2\le C$. You could calculate p on a grid, but I'm not sure if it remains bounded as the mesh tends to zero.

Comment: ...but, I can solve this (using symmetry), and none of the solutions are positive everywhere which, I think, means that this PDE does explode. So, I was wrong. I don't think that $Y_1$ has to be absolutely continuous. Something like $dY_t=(c_0 + c_11_{\{b Y^2_t > 1-t\}})dW_t$ might give a counterexample.

Comment: @George, Thanks for the explanations, it does help.

Comment: @James, Thanks for the proof. It seems correct to me. I originally confused why we only need to show uniform upper bound for some $0<a<1$, not for all $a$. Levy Zero-one law plays a role here.

Answer (score 3):

I have not thought about such questions for a while, but I do not see an immediate mistake in the following reasoning:

Let $Y_t=E[\mathrm{sign}(W_1)| \mathcal{F}_t]$. Then it is a bounded martingale, and it also has a continuous modification since $Y_t=E[\mathrm{sign}(W_1) | W_t]$ and $E[\mathrm{sign}(W_1) | W_t=x]$ depends on $t$ and $x$ continuously. Therefore, it admits a representation via stochastic integral, but $P(Y_t=\pm1 )=1/2$.

This does not contradict the stochastic representation since $\sigma_t$ in it becomes increasingly large if $t$ is close to 1, but the process is far from $\pm1$. This diffusion pushes the process closer to the boundaries of $[-1,1]$.

Is this true, or am I missing something?

Comment: Dear Yuri,
Thanks for the simple construction. It seems to me correct. Except one possible typo: $P(Y_t = \pm 1) = 1/2)$ shall be $P(Y_1 = \pm 1) = 1/2)$? BTW, $Y_t$ admits explicit representation from direct computation:  $Y_t = \sqrt{1-t} ( 1 - 2 \Phi(-W_t/\sqrt{1-t})).$


Comment: Dear Yuri, $\sigma_t$ shall be given bounded as condition,
but your example has to make $\sigma_t$ blow up near 1, 
as you mentioned.

Comment: This all looks correct, except that $\sigma_t$ is not bounded, so is not a counterexample to the original question.

Comment: Yes, I missed the boundedness requirement in the question, sorry. The example given by James is great, I just +1'ed it.

Answer (score 2):

Another counter-example: Let $f:R\to R$ be a non-constant $C^2$ funtion  with $f, f', f''$ all bounded, and such that (i) $f$ vanishes in a non-empty open interval $I$, (ii) $f'>0$ outside the closure of $I$,  and (iii) $E[f(W_1)]=0$. Consider the random variable $Y_1:= f(W_1)$. Clearly $P[Y_1=0]= P[W_1\in I]>0$. The process 
$$
\sigma_t(\omega):=h(t,W_t(\omega)),
$$
where 
$$
h(t,x) :=\cases{\int_R {1\over\sqrt{2\pi(1-t)}} \exp[-(y-x)^2/2(1-t)] f'(y) dy,& 0\le t<1,\cr
0,&t\ge 1,\cr}
$$
is predictable and bounded, and $\sigma_t(\omega)>0$ fo all $t\in[0,1)$ and all $\omega\in \Omega$. Moreover, by Ito's formula,
$$
Y_1=\int_0^1 \sigma_t dW_t,
$$
almost surely. In fact,
$$
E[f(W_1)|{\mathcal F}_s]=\int_0^s \sigma_t\,dW_t,\qquad\forall s>0,
$$
almost surely.